# Mac OS: Mysql, PHP, Apache not working!

Tags: mac, php, apache-http-server, mysql

**Mysql**

```
j:~ julian$ mysql
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

**Apache/PHP**

Forbidden to access / on the server.

Comment: Have you configured Apache at all other than enable Web Sharing in System Preferences -> Sharing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that MySQL is not installed or not included in your path; if it is installed, locate the `mysql` executable and add the directory in which it is located into your PATH environment variable.

For Apache and PHP, make sure that they are set to serve the correct directories (such as `/Library/Webserver`).  They appear to be denied access because they are attempting to serve the root directory `/`.  If the directory is correct, check the permissions and ownership of the directory.